# How do I use .env in Django?

Tags: django, dotenv, python-dotenv

My goal is to email using Python Django without having my email password being shown in the actual code. After some research, I guess I can store my password in an .env file and then access the password from the .env file. So, I currently have an .env file in my Django project with this line of code:

```
export EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

And in my settings.py, I have these:

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST')
print(EMAIL_HOST)
```

But the printed result is None. print(os.environ) spits out something though. How can I get my .env file to work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not only in Django, in general use the library [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
```

Answer (score 8):

https://gist.github.com/josuedjh3/38c521c9091b5c268f2a4d5f3166c497
created a file utils.py in your project.

1: Create an .env file to save your environment variables.

file env.

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=%jjnu7=54g6s%qjfnhbpw0zeoei=$!her*y(p%!&84rs$4l85io
DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST=database
DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME=master
DJANGO_DATABASE_USER=postgres
```

2: For security purposes, use permissions 600 `sudo chmod 600 .env`

3: you can now use the varibles settigns.py

```
from .utils import load_env 

get_env = os.environ.get

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent 

load_env(BASE_DIR / "../.env") #here you indicate where your .env file is

SECRET_KEY = get_env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", "secret")
```

This way it can handle multiple environments  production or stagins

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by importing os and creating a .env file where you will specify all the database details for connection.

**settings.py file:**

```
    import os
    DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        "USER": os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get('DB_USER_PASSWORD'),
        "HOST": os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        "PORT": os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

**.env file:**

```
export DB_NAME = dbname
export DB_USER = root
export DB_USER_PASSWORD = root
export DB_HOST = localhost
export DB_DB_PORT = 5432
```

This example is for PostgreSQL but other DB setup will be exact similar but engine name will need to be changed.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how the environment variables in the .env get imported into the environment. Can you add details about that?