# Django: starting server using a specific database out of multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up 2 databases in django. The second database is meant for testing purposes, so the 2 databases practically have the same models.

My question is how to start the server using the second database.

The steps I did for setting up the databases:

1. I created a second app called 'testing', so now in my project root folder there is the app `api` (the real one) and `testing` (the app meant for the test database). Afterwards, added the same models from `api/models.py` to `testing/models.py`
2. Created router for the first database and the second database:

```
class AuthRouter:

  route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes', 'admin', 'sessions'}

  def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
      if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
          return 'default'
      return None

  def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
      if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
          return 'default'
      return None

  def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name = None, **hints):
      if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
          return db=='default'
      return None

  def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
      if (
          obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
          obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
      ):
          return True
      return None
```

```
class SpotTesting:

    route_app_labels = {'spot_testing'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == "spot_testing":
            return 'test_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == "spot_testing":
            return 'test_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('primary', 'replica1', 'replica2')
        if obj1._state.db == "spot_testing" and obj2._state.db  == "spot_testing":
            return 'test_db'
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name = None, **hints):
        if app_label  == "spot_testing":
            return 'test_db'
        return None
```

3. Edited `api/settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'api.routers.db_routers.AuthRouter',
    'api.routers.TestRouter.SpotTesting',
]

DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': DBNAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    },

    'test_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': "spot_db_testing",
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    }
}
```

4. Ran `python manage.py migrate --database=test_db`[This is how the test db looks after migrations. It looks like the some tables that django would normally create are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE27W.png)

Now I am not sure what command should I run in order to make django `runserver` use the `test_db` instead of the normal one.

Answer (score 1):

Most times, its better to use the easy solutions, it saves time.
For your situation, you can create a .env details for the db you will like to use and specify the **os.environ** credentials to point to.

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': os.environ.get(ENGINE, testEngine),
    'NAME': os.environ.get(DBNAME, testDBNameDefault),
    'USER': os.environ.get(USER, testUserDefault),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get(PASSWORD, testPasswdDefault),
    'HOST': os.environ.get(HOST, localhost),
    'PORT': os.environ.get(PORT, 5432),
},
```

try this, no extra code required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how this works? I do not understand exactly how the environment would use the test db credentials?

Comment: see this other answer on stack overflow for more information on how to use .env files in your project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925571/how-do-i-use-env-in-django