No DATABASE_URL environment variable set, and so no databases setup
While Deploying Django website on AWS EC2 server I am getting error

No DATABASE_URL environment variable set, and so no databases setup.

I Created a gunicon.service file on my server location /home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/LightHouseMediaAgency and set EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/LightHouseMediaAgency/.env to get the environment variables  and in the same location I created a .env file which contain the DATABASE_URL = postgresql://postgres:password@lighthousemediadb.crte3456.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname. I believe that .env file is in the correct location. Also check my DATABASE is set correctly.
production.py


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'lighthousemediadb',
        'USER': "postgres",
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),  # dont keep it hardcoded in production
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': '5432',

        # add these too it improve performance slightly
        'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        'default_transaction_isolation': 'read committed',
        'timezone': 'UTC'
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500




gunicorn.service

    [Unit]
    Description=gunicorn daemon
    Requires=gunicorn.socket
    After=network.target
    
    [Service]
    User=ubuntu
    Group=www-data
    EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/LightHouseMediaAgency/.env
    WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/LightHouseMediaAgency
    ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/.venv/bin/gunicorn \
              --access-logfile - \
              --workers 3 \
              --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
              BE.wsgi:application
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

.env
    SECRET_KEY = 'epmxxxxxxxxxxxxu$0'
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = '3.196.58.181', 'abc.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'
    DB_PASSWORD = 'password'
    DB_HOST = 'lighthousemediadb.crte3456.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
    DATABASE_URL = postgresql://postgres:password@lighthousemediadb.crte3456.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname


Did you test to confirm that it is indeed in the correct location and that it is getting read? For all we know dj_database_url.config() could be doing anything.

@ChukwujiobiCanon How do i check it's getting read or not. i think its getting read because SECRET_KEY is coming from .env file but why not DATABASE_URL.

print db_from_env to see its values.

@RahulVerma:  Could you try to remove spaces variable name, equal sign and value? Could you quote the DATABASE_URL? (if it's not working, could you provide additional info about ubuntu version?) I found several references that specify that spaces between equal sign, values and variable names are not allowed (much like sh / bash / csh / zsh... syntax)

Operating System environment variables are not stored in files. The .env thing is a convention used by some libraries as a convivence to store environment settings in files. Just doing os.environ.get() will only look for actual environment variables, not .env files. Django doesn't read .env files by default. You have to add some library like load_env to make that happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925571/how-do-i-use-env-in-django

@MarkB:  @RahulVerma used the systemd file directive "EnvironmentFile" to source the environment variable file .env: https://www.flatcar.org/docs/latest/setup/systemd/environment-variables/#environmentfile-directive. But again, no spaces should be used between variable names, equal signs and values.

@erny but SECRET_KEY is getting read...

@erny I think .env file is not getting read because when i deleted everthing thing from it. I am not getting SECRET_KEY error. How do I make it readable? I did not find any proper guidance for setting up an environment variable that could be read by server.

$ lxc launch ubuntu:22.04 ub22
Creating ub22
Starting ub22
$ lxc shell ub22
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-virtualenv
...
# sudo su - ubuntu
$ mkdir lighthousemedia && cd lighthousemedia
$ virtualenv .venv && . .venv/bin/activate
(.venv)$ pip install django gunicorn
(.venv)$ django-admin startproject myproj && cd myproj
(.venv)$ ./manage.py migrate

myproj/views.py:
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

ENVVAR = "MYVAR"


def show_envvar_setting(request):
    value = getattr(settings, ENVVAR, '<not defined in settings>')
    return HttpResponse(f'{ENVVAR}={value}', content_type='text/plain')

myproj/urls.py:
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('envvar/', views.show_envvar_setting),
]

myproj/settings.py:
...
import os
MYVAR = os.environ.get('MYVAR', '<not defined in environment>')
...

Test with 2 different terminals.

terminal 1: (.venv)$ /manage runserver
terminal 2: $ wget -O- -nv http://localhost:8000/envvar/ 2>/dev/null

Run test again defining env var:

terminal 1: (.venv)$ MYVAR='testing 1234'
terminal 2: run wget again to see output

Create .env: file and install systemd config:
echo "MYVAR='systemd env file test'" > ~/.env

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/.env
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/myproj
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/lighthousemedia/.venv/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 2 \
      myproj.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Start service and check:
# systemctl daemon-reload   # force reload if systemd files have changed
# systemctl start gunicorn
# journalctl -xeu gunicorn.service
...  # check if it's running and no errors happen
# wget -O- http://localhost:8000/envvar 2>/dev/null

Check that environment variable has been output.
So, to my conclusion, you may have an error in our .env file. I would definitely double check the .env file syntax (ALLOWED_HOSTS line may not be correct) and the settings.py file. You could log this initially to stdout or stderr using print (so it would be part of systemd logs).
